# Gibbon Integration with Moodle

Tags: php, mysql, database, hosting

I want to integrate Gibbon v 10.0.00 (gibbonedu.org) with Moodle 2.6.3. I have followed the instructions on Gibbon website [https://gibbonedu.org/support/administrators/connecting-to-moodle/](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=328167) but i am still not able to integrate because of following error:

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/231044195/public_html/lms/lib/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 443

Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server25.hostinger.co.uk' (110 "Connection timed out") in /home/231044195/public_html/lms/lib/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 443
server25.hostinger.co.uk: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server25.hostinger.co.uk' (110 "Connection timed out")
(mysql): SET NAMES 'utf8'

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u231044195/public_html/lms/lib/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 585
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server25.hostinger.co.uk' (110 "Connection timed out")
Cannot connect the database.

I have posted complete details of error on [this post](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=328167). Please help

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `server25.hostinger.co.uk` configuration, it may deny the external connections to its MySQL (and rightfully so). If it's  a shared hosting, you might try and persuade the hoster to make an exception for you. If you're the owner of the host, you have to allow MySQL to accept the connections from certain IPs (which would be your Moodle server IP).

Also, I must say that Moodle 2.6 is pretty old - the newest stable version is 2.9 now.

Comment: Thanks sergey, I have created a support ticket with my host regarding permission for external database connections, lets see what they say :)